# How to click to the favorite buttons of tweets using selenium javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, twitter

I am trying to favorite tweets using javascript selenium webdriver. What I want to do is search a keyword, go to live tab, favorite the last 50 tweets and follow those people. My favorite tweets part of code fails and I get a

> StaleElementReferenceError: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

error. Here is my code, can you help me how to click to the favorite buttons?

```
var button = driver.findElement(By.className('HeartAnimation'));

function buttoninthearray(driver, i) {
    var buttons = driver.findElements(By.className('HeartAnimation'));
    return webdriver.promise.filter(buttons, function(button) {
        return button.isDisplayed();
    }).then(function(visiblebuttons) {
        return visiblebuttons[i];
    });
}
 for( i = 0; i <limit; i++){
    buttoninthearray(driver, i).then(function(button){
        button.click();
    });
    driver.sleep(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a snippet from the selenium docs on Stale Element Reference Exception:

A common technique used for simulating a tabbed UI in a web app is to prepare DIVs for each tab, but only attach one at a time, storing the rest in variables. In this case, it's entirely possible that your code might have a reference to an element that is no longer attached to the DOM (that is, that has an ancestor which is "document.documentElement").

Here is a link to the docs:
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp

Since you are dealing with a tabbed UI, this might be the issue.

Like the page says, "If WebDriver throws a stale element exception in this case, even though the element still exists, the reference is lost. You should discard the current reference you hold and replace it, possibly by locating the element again once it is attached to the DOM."